# How do I make this sorting functional?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Enter a movie title and your rating. Do this with several movies. when a-z in 'sort' dropdown is clicked, the list of movies should be reordered to be alphabetical.. z-a should make them ordered backwards.. low to high should sort from lowest rating to highest.. high to low should be from 10-1.

https://wrenjupiter.github.io/movies/

I don't think I've ever worked with the sort method before and looking at the docs for it isn't helping me understand how to implement it effectively.

I tried this:

```
 $("#az").on("click", function () {
      $("#movieList").innerHtml("");
      for (let movie of curMovies) {
        const sorted = $(movies).sort();
        $("movieList").append(sorted);
      }
    });
```

but it doesn't do anything. I'm new to this and JavaScript is really hard for me. I'm supposed to use JQuery for it too. I'm using a custom bootstrap style sheet.

This is what I have so far

```
<h1 class="container heading bg-secondary text-light text-center">
      Movies!
    </h1>

    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="">
        <div class="form-group rounded">
          <hr />
          <form id="form" class="row">
            <div class="input-group col-6">
              <label for="title" class="px-3 py-2">Enter a Title:</label>
              <input
                class="text-center form-control"
                type="text"
                id="title"
                name="title"
                placeholder="Deadpool"
                minlength="2"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group col-6">
              <label for="rating" class="px-3 py-1">Enter a Rating:</label>
              <input
                class="text-center form-control"
                type="text"
                id="rating"
                name="rating"
                placeholder="10"
                minlength="0"
                maxlength="10"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 pt-4">
              <button
                type="sumbit"
                id="ad"
                class="btn-block shadow btn btn-success"
              >
                Add To List
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" class="dropdown">
      <button
        class="btn shadow btn-primary dropdown-toggle ml-3"
        type="button"
        id="dropdownMenuButton"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        Sort
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item id='az'" href="#">A - Z</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item id='za'" href="#">Z - A</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item id='lh'" href="#">Low to high</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item id='hl'" href="#">High to low</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul id="movieList"></ul>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    let id = 0;
    let movies = [];
    let ids = [id];

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#ad").on("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        let title = $("#title").val();
        let rating = $("#rating").val();
        let rem = $(
          "<button class='rem shadow btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-circle mx-2'>X</button>"
        );
        let curMovie = { title, rating, id };
        movies.push(curMovie);

        let li = $("<li>");
        li.id = id;
        li.html(curMovie["title"] + ": " + curMovie["rating"]);
        li.append(rem);
        //object wont stringify
        $("#movieList").append(li);
        console.log(curMovie);

        rem.on("click", function () {
          li.remove();
        });
        id++;
      });
    });
```

https://wrenjupiter.github.io/movies/

Comment: what is `curMovies`? what is `movies`? why do you `for (let movie of curMovies) {` then ignore the `movie` variable?

Comment: is this better? $("#az").on("click", function () {
      $("#movieList").innerHtml("");
      for (let title of curMovie) {
        const sorted = $(title).sort();
        $("movieList").append(sorted);
      }

Comment: does it work? then it's better

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are new to JavaScript, I provided a working version. First, the way you are trying to sort the movies using jQuery is not correct. Second, there are some syntax errors in the dropdown items' HTML, Do the following then it will work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Movies</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="container heading bg-secondary text-light text-center">
  Movies!
</h1>

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="">
    <div class="form-group rounded">
      <hr />
      <form id="form" class="row">
        <div class="input-group col-6">
          <label for="title" class="px-3 py-2">Enter a Title:</label>
          <input class="text-center form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Deadpool" pattern=".{2,}" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group col-6">
          <label for="rating" class="px-3 py-1">Enter a Rating:</label>
          <input class="text-center form-control" type="text" id="rating" name="rating" placeholder="10" minlength="0" maxlength="10" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 pt-4">
          <button type="submit" id="ad" class="btn-block shadow btn btn-success">
            Add To List
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn shadow btn-primary dropdown-toggle ml-3" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Sort
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="az" href="#">A - Z</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="za" href="#">Z - A</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="lh" href="#">Low to high</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="hl" href="#">High to low</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <ul id="movieList"></ul>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
  let id = 0;
  let movies = [];
  let ids = [id];

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ad").on("click", function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      let title = $("#title").val();
      let rating = $("#rating").val();
      let rem = $("<button class='rem shadow btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-circle mx-2'>X</button>");
      let curMovie = { title, rating, id };
      movies.push(curMovie);

      let li = $("<li>");
      li.id = id;
      li.html(curMovie["title"] + ": " + curMovie["rating"]);
      li.append(rem);
      $("#movieList").append(li);

      rem.on("click", function () {
        li.remove();
      });
      id++;
    });

    $("#az").on("click", function () {
      movies.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
      displayMovies();
    });

    $("#za").on("click", function () {
      movies.sort((a, b) => b.title.localeCompare(a.title));
      displayMovies();
    });

    $("#lh").on("click", function () {
      movies.sort((a, b) => a.rating - b.rating);
      displayMovies();
    });

    $("#hl").on("click", function () {
      movies.sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating);
      displayMovies();
    });

    function displayMovies() {
      $("#movieList").empty();
      for (let movie of movies) {
        let li = $("<li>");
        li.id = movie.id;
        li.html(movie.title + ": " + movie.rating);
        let rem = $("<button class='rem shadow btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-circle mx-2'>X</button>");
        li.append(rem);
        $("#movieList").append(li);

        rem.on("click", function () {
          li.remove();
        });
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In short, the sort method is used to arrange movies in an array.
The comparison function inside sort determines the order.
localeCompare is used to compare movie titles for alphabetical sorting.
For rating-based sorting, simple numeric comparisons are used.
The variations in the comparison functions control the sorting order. If  you want more detailed ask!

Comment: would you be able to/would you mind helping me find out why minlength isnt working?

Comment: I see that you have minlength specified in your HTML for the title input field. note that the minlength attribute is not a standard attribute for the <input> element. Instead, you should use the minlength attribute for text inputs within a <form>. But still by adding required to the input element you can make it work.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding.. minlength doesnt work for my input but it should work for a text input in a form? my input types are text inside of the form if thats what you mean. i made them required and tried using a pattern and they still dont work

Comment: refer here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/minlength

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference.. <form id="form" class="row">
            <div class="input-group col-6">
              <label for="title" class="px-3 py-2">Enter a Title:</label>
              <input
                class="text-center form-control"
                type="text"
                id="title"
                name="title"
                placeholder="Deadpool"
                minlength="2"
                maxlength="50"
                required
              />

Comment: Now, i fix it use pattern=".{2,}" instead of minlength, it worked and try it here

Comment: it's still not working for me. maxlength is working for me but instead of it saying theres too many it just doesnt let me add any more

Comment: The `maxlength` attribute is designed to limit the number of characters that can be entered into an input field. When the limit is reached, additional characters are not accepted, but the behavior of displaying an error message is not standardized and depends on the browser.